# what's the usecase for int.class, double.class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, primitive

I understand the class literals and the `getClass()` methods how they help with generics and reflection but I don't understand why the same would apply for primitives as well?

For example, for int, I can use `int.class` but not sure what you could do with it.

1. You cannot instantiate via `int.class.newInstance()`, it will throw an `Exception`
2. You cannot use them with generics since those require non-primitives

Any ideas?

Comment: `getClass()` returns a `Class<?>` object representing a class, which you can use in reflection. `int` is a primitive type, you can't use `.class` on it. You **can** use `.class` on actual classes, like `Integer` , which is the class equivalent of `int`. In generics you don't need class objects, you can use just the class name, like `List<Integer>`.
More on generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html
More on reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: `> I can use int.class`
Can you though?

Comment: @pete, I can write it, and it compiles with javac 8. Nothing else limiting me from using it. I assume OP can do that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.  Suppose that you have a class with overloaded methods for primitive arguments; e.g.

```
public class Test {
    public void test(int a) { .... }
    public void test(char a) { .... }
}
```

How can I reflectively obtain the `Method` object for one of the `test` methods?  Answer: by calling (for example):

```
Class<?> testClass = Test.class;
Method method = testClass.getDeclaredMethod("test", int.class);
```

(Note that `Integer.TYPE` can be used as well.)

---

> You cannot instantiate via `int.class.newInstance()`, it will throw an `Exception`

That is because `newInstance()` returns an `Object`, and a primitive value cannot be an object.  But also, consider that:

```
    SomeType.class.newInstance()
```

is equivalent to

```
    new SomeType()
```

and now consider that Java won't let you use `new` to create a primitive value.  (And if it did ... what would you expect the actual value of `new int` to be?)

---

> You cannot use them with generics since those require non-primitives.

That is true, but orthogonal.  You write `List<MyClass>`, not `List<MyClass.class>`.  Class literals don't come into the discussion.